# Fetch API - erro CORS

Tags: javascript, json

Caros, tenho uma aplicação em javascript, usando `fetch API`para buscar as informações em um arquivo estático `.json`. 
Funciona normalmente quando usado em um live server(localhost) no editor VsCode.
Porem quando não executado em um servidor local, ela retorna erro de CORS. Gostaria de entender o porque isto ocorre e como poderia resolver?

```js
document.getElementById('getUsers').addEventListener('click', getUsers);

function getUsers() {
   fetch('users.json')
   .then((res) => res.json())
   .then((data) => {
  let output = '<h2>Users</h2>';
  data.forEach(function(user) {
     output +=
     `
     <ul class="list-group mb-3">
     <li class="list-group-item">ID: ${user.id}</li>
     <li class="list-group-item">Name: ${user.name}</li>
     <li class="list-group-item">Email: ${user.email}</li>
     </ul>
     `;
  });
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = output;
   })
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="display-4 mb-4">Fetch API </h1>
    <div class="d-flex">
      <button class="btn btn-primary mr-4" id="getText">Get Text</button>
      <button class="btn btn-success mr-4" id="getUsers">Get JSON</button>
      <button class="btn btn-warning mr-4" id="getPosts">Get API DATA</button>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div id="output"></div>
  </div>

  <script src="js/connection-index1.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

**Erro:**

```
Fetch API cannot load file:///Users/rodeghiero/Documents/developer/js-ajax-es6/src/users.json. URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request.
getUsers @ connection-index1.js:19
```

Comment: Você está fazendo uma requisição assíncrona utilizando o protocolo `file`? Já tentou rodar sua aplicação dentro de um servidor HTTP?

Comment: Há um tempo atrás tentei executar como gitpages e também deu erro, mas no server localhost não gera.
Desculpe mas não conheço o protocolo "file".

Comment: O protocolo `file`, @MárioRodeghiero, é quando você está executando o arquivo diretamente por ele e não por um servidor `HTTP`. Olhe o o endereço que está retornando no erro: `file:///Users/rod`...

Comment: Entendi @MarcelodeAndrade ! vou aguardar e ver se alguém tem uma solução para rodar com protocolo file ou no gitpages.